# How can I make tags editable inline (or submittable without needing to go to "edit"mode for the Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, tags

I have a model called Company, and in the Show view have the following:

```
<div id = 'tags'>
  <strong>Tags:</strong>
  <% unless @company.tag_list.empty? %>
     <%= @company.tag_list %>
  <% end %>
  <% form_remote_tag(:url => {:action => 'update'},
                     :update => 'tags') do  %>
    <%= text_field :company, :tag_list %>   
       <%= submit_tag 'Save' %> 
  <% end %>
</div>
```

I am using acts_as_taggable_on gem.

This is the update method in the Company controller:

```
  def update
    @company = Company.find(params[:id])
    if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated company."
      redirect_to @company
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
```

I guess my desired result would be I could add tags, see them added via ajax, all without needing to Edit the model but from the show View, kind of like the way you can add tags in Wordpress.

UPDATE:  This is the error I get (it looks like it isn't using the update action:

```
POST http://localhost:3000/companies/10
No action responded to 10. Actions: create, destroy, edit, email_this_week, index, new, show, and update
```

Hmmm, not sure why it is doing that....it should do update action, right?  Do I need to do something in my routes (even though I specified the action?)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there.

First you create a partial `tags` that renders your tags and your ajax-form (that you showed in your question).

Then inside your controller-method you write:

```
def update
  @company = Company.find(params[:id])
  if request.xhr?
    # add the given tag to the company
    @company.tags << params[:company][:taglist]
    @company.save
    render :partial => 'tags'
  else
    if @company.update_attributes(params[:company])
      flash[:notice] = "Successfully updated company."
      redirect_to @company
    else
      render :action => 'edit'
    end
  end
end
```

What i do: i test if the request is an ajax request (`xhr?`) and then try to update the tags from the field that was given: you will have to correct that code i guess. I am assuming just doing `update_attributes` does not work, as you will want to add a tag to a list of existing tags. If that succeeds, you render the partial which will replace the previous, because of the `update`-option you specified in the form.

This should get you started.

To improve it further, you should add to each of your tags an image (a red cross) with a link to remove the given tag.

Comment: thanks!  I wasn't familiar with .xhr? method...that works in 2.3.5?  yeah, I have a feeling that update doesn't work either....let me play around with this, so I take the tag code in the view and make it a partial?

Comment: this was close -- needed to fudge around it and maybe there's a problemw ith the way my instance does routing.

Answer (score 0):

There are some jquery plugins which were called edit-in-place... Maybe this helps you:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/708801/whats-the-best-edit-in-place-plugin-for-jquery

Comment: what do I do in the controller?  one of the plugins I looked at but could never get to work better-edit-in-place had helpers with everything and was REST compliant....like the cocnept, but didn't work....